# How could I prevent the installer to close the application during upgrade

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

If I upgrade my application through the installer UI, it will prompt and ask whether I want to close the running application.

But what if I upgrade it through command? Are there any ways I can prevent it closing my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the reboot at the end of a silent install by setting the REBOOT property to **[ReallySuppress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**. Sample:

```
msiexec /I MySetup.msi REBOOT=ReallySuppress /QN
```

Custom actions in the InstallExecuteSequence sometimes override this behavior and initiates a reboot on their own, but if the MSI is complying with best practice and standards setting REBOOT to ReallySuppress should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

An MSI installer will schedule a reboot for any files it can't replace. This reboot can also be suppressed at the end of the install, but it will still be registered as necessary and the file replacement will not happen until the system has been rebooted.

Comment: Do you know how to suppress this reboot at the end of the install?

Comment: As long as you understand that if you suppress or delay the reboot then the install is not complete because files have not been replaced. The potential issue is that you have a mixture of files in your running app, some have been replaced and some haven't. This often leads to crashes. Also, it's not unusual for later installs to fail to launch because they check for previous unfinished installs, which is what you have unless you reboot.